Trouble with Constraints in Quadratic Programming for Jacobian Estimation Using MATLAB's fmincon
I am trying to implement a simple quadratic program to solve for Jacobian but no matter what I try it always exceeds my constraints. The problem is simple quadratic programming

% Objective function: Minimize the norm of Delta J
objFun = @(deltaJ) norm(deltaJ,2);

% Solve optimization problem to find Delta J(k+1)
deltaJ_init = 0.05; % Initial guess for Delta J(k+1)
options = optimoptions('fmincon', ...
'Algorithm', 'interior-point', ...
'Display', 'iter-detailed', ...
'ConstraintTolerance', 1e-9, ...
'StepTolerance', 1e-9, ...
'OptimalityTolerance', 1e-6, ...
'MaxIter', 10000, ...
'MaxFunEvals', 10000, ...
'Diagnostics', 'on');

% nonlcon = @(deltaJ) constraints(deltaJ, J_updates(k-1), delta_q, delta_z, predicted_q(k));
nonlcon = @(deltaJ) constraints(deltaJ, J_updates(k-1), predicted_delta_q(k-1), delta_z, predicted_q(k));


[deltaJ_opt, ~] = fmincon(objFun, deltaJ_init, [], [], [], [], lb, ub, nonlcon, options);

delta_jopt(k)=deltaJ_opt;
% Update J(k+1) and store it
J_k_plus_1 = J_updates(k-1) + deltaJ_opt;
J_updates(k) = J_k_plus_1;

% Predict Δq(k+1) using the updated J(k+1)
predicted_delta_q(k) = 1 / J_k_plus_1 * delta_z;
predicted_q(k+1) = predicted_q(k)+  predicted_delta_q(k);

My constraint function is defined as follows
function [c, ceq] = constraints(deltaJ, J_k, delta_q_k, delta_z_k, q)
    ceq = (J_k + deltaJ) * delta_q_k - delta_z_k;  % Equality constraint
    c = (q + delta_q_k) - 2;                      % Inequality constraint

    % Debugging output
    fprintf('q: %f, delta_q_k: %f, c: %f\n', q, delta_q_k, c);
end

Despite these settings, the constraints are consistently violated, especially the inequality constraint, which should ensure q + delta_q_k <= 2.

